# What is the definition of$\mathcal{Mod} P$ counting complexity class?

Tags: complexity-theory

**Question :** What is the definition of $\mathcal{Mod} P$ counting complexity class?

I am not getting anything relevant about this complexity class on Google search. If it is available on Wikipedia, please share a link.

$\mathcal{Mod} P$:  A set $L$ is in the class $\mathcal{Mod} P$ if there exist functions $f \in \#\mathcal{P} $ and $g \in \mathcal{FP}$ such that string $x$, and $g(x) = 0^p$ for some prime $p$ and

$$x \in L \iff f(x) \ncong 0 \pmod{p}\,.$$

I am not able to understand what it is mean by  $g(x) = 0^p$ for some prime $p$.

**Reference  :** Köbler and Toda, *On the Power of Generalized MOD-Classes*. In *Proceedings of 8th Annual Structure in Complexity Conference*, IEEE, 1993. [PDF](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=336531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class ModP is defined in Definition 3.1 on page 3 of your reference.

The abstract of the paper clearly states that the paper studies the computational power of the *new* counting class ModP. This suggests that this class is *introduced* in the paper, and in particular, is *defined* in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

The string $0^p$ is simply the string containing $p$ zeroes.